# Display content only on child-page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to change the header only on the child pages of the page id=261. 
I wanna display a text above the menu only on those.

I was thinking in something like `<?php if(is_page('page name')){ ?> <div id="text-above"></div> <?php } ?>`

But I'm not sure how to check if page is a child of page 261.

```
    <header class="site-header no-fixed-header">
            <div class="bnt-container">

                <?php mobile_menu(); ?>

                <?php logo(); ?>

                <div class="text-above">Menu title child pages</div>

                <?php primary_menu(); ?>

            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Are you using WordPress?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the tag before, the correct is WordPress! @j08691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $post->post_parent to check if the current page parent id is 261

```
if ( '261' == $post->post_parent ) { 
    do some thing
 }
```

for more info [see this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/if-page-is-parent-or-child/)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot